# C++ make_shared calling destructor twice

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have some code that's confusing me.  I've been learning about shared_pointers and am following a guide on youtube.  I am using make_shared to construct my Dog, and assign the shared pointer to p.

```
class Dog
{
    private:
        std::string name;
    public:
        Dog(std::string _name):
            name(_name)
        {
            std::cout << "Creating dog with name " << name << std::endl;
        }

        ~Dog() { std::cout << "Destroying dog!" << std::endl; }

        void bark()
        {
            std::cout << name << " barks like a Dog! Woof!" << std::endl;
        }
};

std::shared_ptr<Dog> foo()
{
    std::cout << "Entering foo" << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<Dog> p = std::make_shared<Dog>("Tank"); //will be deleted when freed off stack

    std::cout << "Dog use count = " << p.use_count() << std::endl;

    std::shared_ptr<Dog> p2 = p;

    std::cout << "Dog use count = " << p.use_count() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Returning first pointer from foo!" << std::endl;
    return p;
}
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Dog> p = foo();

    std::cout << "Dog use count = " << p.use_count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ shared_ptr.cpp
```

However, here is my output:

```
Entering foo
Creating dog with name Tank
Destroying dog!
Destroying dog!
Dog use count = 1
Dog use count = 2
Returning first pointer from foo!
```

Could someone explain the logic of constructing and then double destructing somehow?

Comment: You should pay attention to *which* instance is being destructed. Step through in a debugger to find out. You may have created an accidental copy in this code.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33d2a00ca83d2bdc).  What compiler and version are you using?  Do you have optimizations turned on?

Comment: Tip: Accept string arguments as `const std::string&` to avoid making endless, pointless copies.

Comment: You should show the code calling `foo`. Also note that `Dog` class has implicit copy constructor and assignment operators.

Comment: @tadman In this case, that advice is wrong, because it means at least one copy needs to be made, namely from the parameter to the member. To minimize copies, accept the argument by value and then move it into the member.

Comment: The given code still [does not produce the specified output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6G7TqpLxP5zoDmbh)

Comment: I have updated the code with my main function.  I'm actually on a mac, g++ version: Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4).  I am going to try running on a centos vm and see what behavior I get.

Comment: @VTT this output is what I would expect to see.

Comment: Why would you expect to see two dogs being destroyed after creating just one?

Comment: I don't get the output from the question either: https://ideone.com/KcDC32

Comment: @VTT I'm saying that the output you linked is the output I would expect to see.  My question is asking why there are two destructors called.

Comment: Make sure you do a clean build. I don't expect the compiler to mess this up.

Comment: @Brian Accepting argument by value will actually maximize copies. For example You have an instance of `std::string` and pass it into constructor, then a temporary `std::string` object is copy created then it will be moved into class field and then destroyed. This temporary object is worthless.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]. Your example is not complete

Comment: @briansrls But there are no two destructors called... The output you've listed in your question does not happen. Most likely you got it from code that is different from the code posted or something else...

Comment: @VTT If you want to keep the original value around, then you *must* make at least one copy. Accepting the argument by value does create an extra object, but doesn't make any extra copies compared to accepting by const reference.

Comment: @Brian Why would you want to create an extra object anyway?

Comment: @VTT In OP's case, where they're passing a string literal, passing by const reference guarantees that two copies must be made. Why would you want that?

Comment: @Brian VTT is saying accepting by value and moving is a copy plus a move.  accepting by const reference is just a copy, so it is cheaper.

Comment: @NathanOliver nevertheless, if you are passing a string literal, passing by value means 1 copy + 1 move, whereas passing by const reference means 2 copies.

Comment: @Brian Where is the second copy?  If you get a string literal then you have a constructor call and then a copy.  If you are passed an lvalue you just have a copy.  with pass by value and move you have a constructor call and a move for the string literal and a copy and move for an lvalue.  In both cases no one copies twice.

Comment: @VTT This behavior is reproducible on a random macOS vm I have.  If you would like detailed instructions on how to reproduce it please let me know.  This turned out to be an environment issue, so it seems obvious you may have problems reproducing.

Comment: You missed something: there are more constructors than you think, and you didn’t instrument those. What happens is that a copy of your object is made, but you didn’t instrument the copy constructor. You also need to instrument the move constructor. Then you’ll see that the number of constructor and destructor calls is the same. And that’s the only concern of yours: whether a copy or move is performed, or none, is beside the point here. You wondered why there’s seeming double-destruction: there of course isn’t.

Comment: @NathanOliver The call to the constructor of `std::string` from a string literal does basically the same work as the copy constructor. It copies the characters from the string literal to the `std::string` storage.

Comment: @Brian I don't think I understand your argument, wouldn't copying a reference be much quicker in this example, rather than copying a string by value and then copying that argument into the private member.  With pass by reference, we dont copy the whole string, but the location of the string (which is very small in comparison).  And then, we copy the string into the private member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.

I tried compiling on centos with

```
g++ shared_ptr.cpp
```

But the compiler complains that shared_ptr is not a part of std.  Changing to

```
g++ -std=c++11 shared_ptr.cpp
```

makes compilation successful, and I see the behavior I would expect (no double destruction).

My mac's makefile only specified

```
g++ shared_ptr.cpp
```

I checked my default c standard on my mac, and it is set to 199711L (1997ish).  Even though this is not c++11, it seems like it was able to compile although the behavior is obviously weird.

On centOS, the default std is also 199711L, but compilation failed.  It sounds like this is undefined behavior and very dangerous.